# Почему при умножении длин в разных мерах измерения получается разный результат?

Tags: математика

1м=100см
20см×20см=400см=4м
Переводим сантиметры в метры
0,2м×0,2м=0,04м=4см
Как мы ведь просто перевели сантиметры в метра, а число уже другое??

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не по тематике сайта.

Comment: Старая хохма, как из 5 копеек получить 50... Эх, птенцы гнезда ЕГЭшного

Answer (score 1):

Вы умножаете числа, но меры не умножаете, это ошибка.
20см×20см=400см<sup>2</sup> (20*20 и см*см).
Так же 0,2м×0,2м=0,04м<sup>2</sup> то есть это 0.04 метра квадратных , а квадратный метр это 100см*100см, то есть 10000см<sup>2</sup> вот от этой величины и берите 0.04